# HashSet conversion to List

Tags: c#, list, set

I have looked this up on the net but I am asking this to make sure I haven't missed out on something. Is there a built-in function to convert HashSets to Lists in C#? I need to avoid duplicity of elements but I need to return a List.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
   using System.Linq;
   HashSet<int> hset = new HashSet<int>();
   hset.Add(10);
   List<int> hList= hset.ToList();
```

HashSet is, by definition, containing no duplicates. So there is no need for `Distinct`.

Comment: Related to this, if I have an ordered list and I do 

orderedList.Distinct().ToList() could you tell me if it retains the order in the orderedList? It serves my purpose if it ensures that it always retains the first occurence of the duplicate element and gets rid of the later occurence.(I have the list ordered by relevance...need the more relevant one to be retained)

Comment: @Ngu there is no point using Distinct() on a HashSet as there will be no duplicates anyway

Comment: @Simon...Exactly what I was wondering...any idea why there is a Distinct() method available on the HashSet to start with?

Comment: @atlantis - Distinct comes with enumerable

Answer (score 20):

Two equivalent options:

```
HashSet<string> stringSet = new HashSet<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
// LINQ's ToList extension method
List<string> stringList1 = stringSet.ToList();
// Or just a constructor
List<string> stringList2 = new List<string>(stringSet);
```

Personally I'd prefer calling `ToList` is it means you don't need to restate the type of the list.

Contrary to my previous thoughts, both ways allow covariance to be easily expressed in C# 4:

```
    HashSet<Banana> bananas = new HashSet<Banana>();        
    List<Fruit> fruit1 = bananas.ToList<Fruit>();
    List<Fruit> fruit2 = new List<Fruit>(bananas);
```

Answer (score 9):

```
List<ListItemType> = new List<ListItemType>(hashSetCollection);
```

Answer (score 7):

There is the Linq extension method `ToList<T>()` which will do that (It is defined on `IEnumerable<T>` which is implemented by `HashSet<T>`).

Just make sure you are `using System.Linq;`

As you are obviously aware the `HashSet` will ensure you have no duplicates, and this function will allow you to return it as an `IList<T>`.