# HashSet<string> as listbox's data source

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to use HashSet as listbox's data source in order to fill its content:

```
HashSet<string> brCodes = new HashSet<string>();
listBoxBrcodes.DataSource = brCodes;
```

I'm getting `ArgumentException` during assign operation.

What is the best way to use `HashSet` as source of `listBox`?

Comment: is it winforms? don't forget to add appropriate tags to the question

Comment: I'm using winforms.

Comment: @CodeCaster Wow! 800+ questions! 

Comment: convert it to a list...see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430987/hashset-conversion-to-list

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy why did you reopen?

Comment: @CodeCaster duplicate was about `DataGridView`. I would close it as *Unclear what you are asking*, but not for that duplicate

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, the DataSource object has to implement either
IList, IListSource interfaces, or be a DataSet or an Array.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource?view=netframework-4.7.2