# Adding values from nested array into uniques list with better efficiency

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I am using C#,
I got a document with a nested array - here is a simplified example of its data structure (as a json) -

```
{
    "property1": "...",
    "property2": "...",
    "lines": [
        "lineProp1": "..",
        "lineProp2": "..",
        "nestedItems": [
            {
               "nestedValue": "12345"
            },
            {
               "nestedValue": "1111"
            }
         ]
     ]
}
```

I need to run on this document, for each line, run on its nested items, for each nested item add the `nestedValue` to a new list and only do so for unique values (no duplications).

The easiest way is to just do something like:

```
foreach(line in lines) 
   foreach(nestedItem in line.nestedItems)
       check if nestedItem.nestedValue exists already exists in my new list,
       if not add it.
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. 
I am probably going to have a pretty heavy traffic going through this logic.

A bit of context: 
I am trying to extract a set of document ids with which I then going to lock those resources via redis caching so shared data wont get processed at the same time. But I want to make the logic around this lock/unlock mechanism as efficient as possible and this is part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to find duplicates in a List, costs a lot. It's much easier and faster to do these kind of checks from a [HashSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.8) (I will research and update retrieval times - Can't find hard values, but in theory it should be O(1) for Hash based data structures and O(N) for lists).

**Warning**: The HashSet can't be ordered and does not allow duplicates whatsoever.

So you can keep the code and do the following

```
foreach(line in lines) 
   foreach(nestedItem in line.nestedItems)
       // Just add to the HashSet. If it exists it will not add it at all
```

> Returns: Boolean
>
> true if the element is added to the HashSet object;
>
> false if the element is already present.

Quoting from documentation.

> The HashSet class is based on the model of mathematical sets and
>   provides high-performance set operations similar to accessing the keys
>   of the Dictionary or Hashtable collections. In simple
>   terms, the HashSet class can be thought of as a
>   Dictionary collection without values.
>
> A HashSet collection is not sorted and cannot contain duplicate
>   elements. If order or element duplication is more important than
>   performance for your application, consider using the List class
>   together with the Sort method.

To convert to list just [check this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430987/hashset-conversion-to-list)

Comment: Or you can directly `Add()` it and check the return value. If it returned `false`, then item already existed.

Answer (score -1):

It's possible to obtain better performance with Xpath Json query.
By exemple with Newtonsoft library.

```cs
JObject json = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
var nestedValuesFromJson = json.SelectTokens("$.lines.nestedItems[:].nestedValue").Values<String>().Distinct();
```

Full exemple

https://dotnetfiddle.net/FsbERA

Comment: Did you measure this? Or just speculation that it might be better?

Comment: just speculation. it's possible to find a library that doesn't load all json to browse it. it leads to a smaller memory footprint especially for the very large json